# Dynamic C - char pointers, strcpy, strcat

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat, char-pointer

Here is my code:

```
nodebug void sendLogPacketS(char *func, char *msg)
{
    char * log;
    memset(log, 0, strlen(func) + strlen(msg) + 1);
    strcpy(log, func);
    strcat(log, ": ");
    strcat(log, msg);
    sendUDPLogPacket(log, strlen(log));
}
```

It's supposed to take two strings, concatenate them together, then pass the new string and its length to a different function. I'm using Dynamic C 9.62, which doesn't have support for the `malloc` function, so I'm using memset instead.

The problem is when I printf the value of `log` before it's passed to `sendUDPLogPacket`, it contains garbage `DynamiCUniversal Rabbit BIOS Version 9.50\?^>j`. Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: `memset()` fills memory that's already been allocated. It does *not* allocate memory. `log` is pointing to a random location which (luckily) in your case doesn't seem to be writeable, so you're printing faulty data instead of just crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.

You cannot validly access the memory pointed at by an uninitialized pointer, like you do.

The `memset()` function writes to memory, it does not magically allocate new memory (it takes as *input* the pointer to the memory to be written), you cannot in anyway use it "instead of" `malloc()`.

You can try with an on-stack buffer:

```
char log[128] = "";
```

of course you need to *take care* not to use more than 128 characters; your unbounded `strcat()` usage is dangerous.

If your fringe compiler supports C99 you can of course do:

```
const size_t flen = strlen(func);
const size_t mlen = strlen(msg);
char log[flen + 2 + mlen + 1];  // Space for func, msg, colon, space, terminator.
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array of chars with the size of `func` + size of `msg` instead of an uninitialized char pointer.